# Create a button on list view page to copy items to another list

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

i guys,

So my scenario is the following:

We have list A and list B, I want to add a button to list A (maybe in content editor web part) to copy the selected list items (multiple items) to list B, I've tried to add a ribbon button, but it doesn't work when multiple items selected (the button become grayed out when more than one item selected), so I decided to change my approach since I don't have any programming experience and create a button with javascript code that coping the selected items to list B.

List A includes the following columns: Publication name, category, format

List B includes the following columns: Requester name (created by column), publications selected.

So when the user select items the button should create a new list item in list B, with created name and selected publications. I've done this through a simple workflow. Any ideas!
Any 3rd party tools are welcomed

Thanks